# TFS & Feature Branching: How to associate a work item with a source control branch

Tags: version-control, tfs, branch, tfs-workitem

Our branching strategy is Feature Branch (i.e. a branch is created for each feature. Once a feature is ready to deploy, it is merged into the Main branch and deployed.)

As part of the workflow, an R&D manager needs to create a new Work Item for a feature and instruct the developer to implement the feature on a particular branch.

From all the reading I've done, I haven't seen a way to do this BEFORE implementation. I've seen suggestions on how to get a list of Work Items implemented in a specific branch, but none of them cover a way for a manager to indicate which branch a feature should be implemented in.

I've also seen people try to "solve" the problem by attacking the premise: Having too many branches is not a good idea, etc. I don't want to debate the wisdom of Feature Branching. Its advantages (e.g. being able to develop many features in parallel and deploy each feature when ready without having to wait for other features to be ready) are obvious.

Can someone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Microsoft free TFS (*.visualstudio.com)

Answer (score 2):

I've used either the Area or the Iteration field to map to Features that are being created depending on the size or length of feature development.

Each Release would get a Dev branch, and long running features were branched on their own. Minor enhancements would be worked on in the Release Dev Branch (Dev12.1, Dev12.2). These teams had priority over merging to Main, while the feature branches had to time their delivery into the release cycle where the integration would be incorporated into the main release teams capacity.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of several options.

A straightforward way is to add a Link of VersionedItem type to the Feature Work Item using the server path to the branch (e.g. $/MyProject/Features/MyBranch).
[image]

Another way is to use the Tag, using some convention like "Branch=Name".

Comment: Thanks, Giulio! This seems like a really cool idea. The one problem I can find with it  is that you can't query work items based on versioned item links, so if I wanted to get a list of all work items in a specific branch, I wouldn't be able to do that. Is that correct or is there still a way to do that?

Comment: You are right: if you need querying, you must resort to Tags or a custom field.

Comment: Now I see that you are using VS Online, which does not allow custom fields. You are restricted to Tags (or some convention in the Description)

Answer (score 1):

TFS doesn't provide any specific support for this. I can suggest a couple ways, neither of which is all that great:

1. Name the branch after the work item it's for (possibly with the WI ID in the branch name).
2. Create a WI Type called Branch, and create one of these for each branch you have. Then use WI Links to associate them with your features.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a branch for each feature, and a user story for the feature. Then create all tasks needed to deliver the feature as child work items of the user story.

Then use a simple process, such as the user story name being the same as the branch name, or the user story description stating the branch to be used, or add a Tag or Area Path on each work item to indicate the branch.

If you then relate checkins to the tasks, TFS will link the tasks to the change sets, and the change sets to the branch, so you will be able to pick up the relationships programmatically as/when required.

Comment: I like your idea. How about using the "Iteration" field to create an artificial iteration for each branch? Do you think that would work?

Comment: It would work, but I'm not sure it conceptually fits the intent of iterations... some tools our reports may be confused by this, which could cause problems in the future.